# How to avoid running test cases twice using maven command

Tags: maven, selenium

I am developing a test automation project. I run the test cases with testNg plugin in eclipse. That's fine. But when I run test using mvn test command, maven runs the test cases twice. Things become worse when it execute from jenkins. It takes long time to finish all the test cases. 
How could I fix the issue. My POM file is like below-

Please let me know how mvn command just run test cases only once. 
Thanks
Rashed

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/resources/pageproperty</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>main/InspirxTest</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                            <directory>src/main/java/resources/InspirxTestAutomation</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <!-- Configuring the test suites to check executed fine -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/testNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-ixlib-junitsupport</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${basedir}/lib/forLocalRepos/ixlib-junitsupport.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>com.inspirx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ixlib-junitsupport</artifactId>
                            <version>5.2.3</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-ojdbc</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${basedir}/lib/forLocalRepos/ojdbc8.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>com.inspirx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                            <version>8</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server-coreless</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-20081010.060147</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.inspirx</groupId>
            <artifactId>ixlib-junitsupport</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.inspirx</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you share some parts of the logs? I don't see why the tests should run twice. What command do you use to build (`clean install`?)

Comment: Follow convention over configuration. Why have you configured resources in `src/test/java`. Resources for tests belong to `src/test/resources`...

Answer (score 0):

There exists multiple plugins, which might be enabling multiple executions. 'maven-surefire-plugin' is sufficient enough to run the tests, you may try commenting other plugins one by one and check which one is running the tests again.